# PHP absolute relative URL issue during site migration

Tags: php

I am migrating my PHP files to a new server. On the old server, I have used absolute URLs in my `require_once` and `include_once` directives. To be clearer, the absolute URLs specify the location from where `index.html` is stored.

However, the new server requires relative URLs. So if `A.php` requires to include `B.php`, the relative path to `B.php` from `A` must be specified.

Is there a setting in `php.ini` which enforces the PHP interpreter to accept absolute URLs?

Comment: Are you sure the absolute paths on both servers are exactly the same?  That can happen, but does not always happen.

Comment: That's not an absolute "URL", but an absolute filesystem "path". And no, you cannot remap paths. You can craft symlinks, given root priviliges etc.

Comment: Both are thus relative as pointed out, but on the old server it is relative to `index.html` whilst on the new server it is relative to `A.php` in the example. How can I configure the new server to accept my URLs as relative to `index.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way of configuring your new server to accept your URLs as relative to `index.html`.

You are looking for a directive `include_path` in your `php.ini`. 
The solution is to create php.ini file in the same directory with `index.html` (in the root directory of your site) and set:

```
include_path="/path/to/your/directory"
```

Then, all the `include` and `require` instructions will try to search the file in the specified directory first.

Here is the documentation for this directive: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Note that not all hosting providers will let you use your own `php.ini` file. I mean, sometimes that new `php.ini` is just ignored. Then, you will need to find a way of changing the original `php.ini`

Other way is using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` constant:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/file.php';
```

Comment: Although not quite helped me, perhaps due to server restrictions as you pointed out. But for future purposes, might help someone stumbling on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. If You set path to `var/www/something.php` it is relative, if You set path to `/var/www/something.php` (or `C:\\var\\www\\something.php` in windows) it is absolute

Comment: Thnks for pointing out. Both are relative then, but on the old server it is relative to `index.html` and on the new server it is relative to the file trying to include.